# Flutter : Handle screen when notification opened

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

I'm testing push notifications in my Flutter app using Firebase Cloud Messaging API requests. So far, the notifications work well but I can't handle the navigation when the notification is clicked. Here's the function I call in `main.dart` :

```
Future<void> setupMessages() async {
    RemoteMessage? message =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

    if (message != null) {
      handleNavigation(message, context); 
    }

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      handleNavigation(message, context); 
    });
  }

  void handleNavigation(RemoteMessage message, BuildContext context) {
    if (message.data['type'] == 'request') {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, UserRequests.id);
      print('NOTIFICATION TYPE =====> ${message.data['type']}');
    }
  }

 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setupMessages(context);
  }
```

And here's the body of my request :

```
{
  "to": <User token>,
  "notification": {
    "title": "Title",
    "body": "Body"
  },
  "data": {
    "type": "request"
  }
}
```

When I click on the notification with the app opened in background, I'm redirected to the main page of the app but not on the `UserRequests()` page. I checked the routes are fine, and when I print(type) == 'request' so I don't understand why it's not working.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research, I found a solution. The problem was linked to the BuildContext, so I added the `NavigatorState`. Here's the updated code in `main.dart` :

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  Future<void> setupMessages(
      BuildContext context, NavigatorState navigator) async {
    RemoteMessage? message =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

    if (message != null) {
      handleNavigation(message, context, navigator);
    }

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      handleNavigation(message, context, navigator);
    });
  }

  void handleNavigation(
      RemoteMessage message, BuildContext context, NavigatorState navigator) {
    if (message.data['type'] == 'request') {
      navigator.pushNamed(UserRequests.id);
    }
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      setupMessages(context, navigatorKey.currentState!);
    });
  }
```

Also need to add the `navigatorKey` :

```
MaterialApp(
  // ...
  navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
  // ...
)
```

Hoping that it will help someone !